# python dict overwriting other values with unique keys

Tags: python, dictionary, overwrite

I'm making a graph model to store scans from nmap scans.  There is a GraphModel, Vertex, and Edge class, with an NmapDataModel class acting as a wrapper around the GraphModel.  When I've ingested multiple ip addresses into it, it takes the most recent IP and vertex properties and overwrites those properties, but keeps the correct key value (which is a hash of the values that make the vertex unique).  Any help would be greatly appreciated...pulling my hair out...
The main program.  The print statement on line 52 shows the issue.

edit: The problem that I'm having is that each key IS unique, but all values in the shared graph model takes on the last value written using the NmapDataModel.add_ipv4() function.  The keys are unique, they are a hash created by taking the label and the ipv4 address.

```
    class NmapDataModel(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.graphmodel = graph.GraphModel()

        def add_ipv4(self, ipAddress, properties={}):
            properties['ipv4'] = ipAddress
            v = graph.Vertex('IP', properties=properties, unique_by=['ipv4'])
            return self.graphmodel.add_vertex(v)

    class NmapInterface(object):
        def build_model(self, filename=None):
            dm = NmapDataModel()
            tree = ET.parse(filename)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for host in root.findall('host'):
                ipAddressFromHostStuff = some process that gets the IP there
                dm.add_ipv4(ipAddressFromHostStuff)
                for item in dm.graphmodel.vertices:
                    print(item, dm.graphmodel.vertices[item])
            return dm.graphmodel

    class GraphModel(object):
        def __init__(self, graphDict=None):
            self.vertices = dict()
            self.edges = dict()

        def add_vertex(self, vertex):
            if(not vertex.id in self.vertices):
                self.vertices.update({vertex.id:vertex})
            else:
                self.vertices[vertex.id].properties.update(vertex.properties)
            return self.vertices[vertex.id]

    class Vertex(object):
        def __init__(self, label, properties={}, unique_by=[]):
            self.label = label
            id = label
            if(unique_by):
                for item in unique_by:
                    id += ':' + str(properties.get(item,'None'))
            else:
                for item in properties.keys():
                    id += ':' + str(properties.get(item,'None'))
            id = hashlib.md5(id.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[0:10]
            properties['hashcode'] = id
            self.id = id
            self.properties = properties
```

Example output

```
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.5', 'hashcode': '192c6e67b6'}
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.7', 'hashcode': '9a4b1c6c9f'}
    9a4b1c6c9f IP:9a4b1c6c9f:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.7', 'hashcode': '9a4b1c6c9f'}
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.8', 'hashcode': 'fdb4251f16'}
    9a4b1c6c9f IP:9a4b1c6c9f:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.8', 'hashcode': 'fdb4251f16'}
    fdb4251f16 IP:fdb4251f16:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.8', 'hashcode': 'fdb4251f16'}
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.10', 'hashcode': '6c5d6cc9ec'}
    9a4b1c6c9f IP:9a4b1c6c9f:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.10', 'hashcode': '6c5d6cc9ec'}
    fdb4251f16 IP:fdb4251f16:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.10', 'hashcode': '6c5d6cc9ec'}
    6c5d6cc9ec IP:6c5d6cc9ec:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.10', 'hashcode': '6c5d6cc9ec'}
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.13', 'hashcode': '12284ae326'}
    9a4b1c6c9f IP:9a4b1c6c9f:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.13', 'hashcode': '12284ae326'}
    fdb4251f16 IP:fdb4251f16:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.13', 'hashcode': '12284ae326'}
    6c5d6cc9ec IP:6c5d6cc9ec:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.13', 'hashcode': '12284ae326'}
    12284ae326 IP:12284ae326:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.13', 'hashcode': '12284ae326'}
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.14', 'hashcode': 'b8e17aacb6'}
    9a4b1c6c9f IP:9a4b1c6c9f:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.14', 'hashcode': 'b8e17aacb6'}
    fdb4251f16 IP:fdb4251f16:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.14', 'hashcode': 'b8e17aacb6'}
    6c5d6cc9ec IP:6c5d6cc9ec:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.14', 'hashcode': 'b8e17aacb6'}
    12284ae326 IP:12284ae326:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.14', 'hashcode': 'b8e17aacb6'}
    b8e17aacb6 IP:b8e17aacb6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.14', 'hashcode': 'b8e17aacb6'}
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.22', 'hashcode': '8ec5f874b7'}
    9a4b1c6c9f IP:9a4b1c6c9f:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.22', 'hashcode': '8ec5f874b7'}
    fdb4251f16 IP:fdb4251f16:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.22', 'hashcode': '8ec5f874b7'}
    6c5d6cc9ec IP:6c5d6cc9ec:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.22', 'hashcode': '8ec5f874b7'}
    12284ae326 IP:12284ae326:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.22', 'hashcode': '8ec5f874b7'}
    b8e17aacb6 IP:b8e17aacb6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.22', 'hashcode': '8ec5f874b7'}
    8ec5f874b7 IP:8ec5f874b7:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.22', 'hashcode': '8ec5f874b7'}
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.24', 'hashcode': '635dcc2038'}
    9a4b1c6c9f IP:9a4b1c6c9f:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.24', 'hashcode': '635dcc2038'}
    fdb4251f16 IP:fdb4251f16:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.24', 'hashcode': '635dcc2038'}
    6c5d6cc9ec IP:6c5d6cc9ec:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.24', 'hashcode': '635dcc2038'}
    12284ae326 IP:12284ae326:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.24', 'hashcode': '635dcc2038'}
    b8e17aacb6 IP:b8e17aacb6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.24', 'hashcode': '635dcc2038'}
    8ec5f874b7 IP:8ec5f874b7:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.24', 'hashcode': '635dcc2038'}
    635dcc2038 IP:635dcc2038:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.24', 'hashcode': '635dcc2038'}
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.31', 'hashcode': 'c7daaefc8d'}
    9a4b1c6c9f IP:9a4b1c6c9f:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.31', 'hashcode': 'c7daaefc8d'}
    fdb4251f16 IP:fdb4251f16:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.31', 'hashcode': 'c7daaefc8d'}
    6c5d6cc9ec IP:6c5d6cc9ec:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.31', 'hashcode': 'c7daaefc8d'}
    12284ae326 IP:12284ae326:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.31', 'hashcode': 'c7daaefc8d'}
    b8e17aacb6 IP:b8e17aacb6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.31', 'hashcode': 'c7daaefc8d'}
    8ec5f874b7 IP:8ec5f874b7:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.31', 'hashcode': 'c7daaefc8d'}
    635dcc2038 IP:635dcc2038:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.31', 'hashcode': 'c7daaefc8d'}
    c7daaefc8d IP:c7daaefc8d:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.31', 'hashcode': 'c7daaefc8d'}
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.35', 'hashcode': '53273bad7d'}
    9a4b1c6c9f IP:9a4b1c6c9f:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.35', 'hashcode': '53273bad7d'}
    fdb4251f16 IP:fdb4251f16:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.35', 'hashcode': '53273bad7d'}
    6c5d6cc9ec IP:6c5d6cc9ec:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.35', 'hashcode': '53273bad7d'}
    12284ae326 IP:12284ae326:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.35', 'hashcode': '53273bad7d'}
    b8e17aacb6 IP:b8e17aacb6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.35', 'hashcode': '53273bad7d'}
    8ec5f874b7 IP:8ec5f874b7:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.35', 'hashcode': '53273bad7d'}
    635dcc2038 IP:635dcc2038:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.35', 'hashcode': '53273bad7d'}
    c7daaefc8d IP:c7daaefc8d:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.35', 'hashcode': '53273bad7d'}
    53273bad7d IP:53273bad7d:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.35', 'hashcode': '53273bad7d'}
    ============
    192c6e67b6 IP:192c6e67b6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
    9a4b1c6c9f IP:9a4b1c6c9f:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
    fdb4251f16 IP:fdb4251f16:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
    6c5d6cc9ec IP:6c5d6cc9ec:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
    12284ae326 IP:12284ae326:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
    b8e17aacb6 IP:b8e17aacb6:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
    8ec5f874b7 IP:8ec5f874b7:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
    635dcc2038 IP:635dcc2038:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
    c7daaefc8d IP:c7daaefc8d:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
    53273bad7d IP:53273bad7d:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
    021890997d IP:021890997d:{'ipv4': '10.11.1.39', 'hashcode': '021890997d'}
```

Comment: There is just way too much code here. Can you please bring it down to a [mcve]?

Comment: Is the problem specific to neo4j modules and graph, or can you demonstrate the issue without third party libraries?

Comment: Way too much code with little or no context. But I get the impression you haven't understood that in dictionaries, **keys must be unique**.